# How to use Excel Switch function to compare with range of values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to use the SWITCH function to detect if a number is between two other numbers, if not test the next range of numbers and so on.

The objective is to have a one cell answer and then copy the formula over a column (of dates in this example).

I tried this :

```
=SWITCH(MONTH(44562);{1;2;3};"T1";{4;5;6};"T2";{7;8;9};"T3";{10;11;12};"T4")
```

But the function spills for each element of the array and the comparison is done by level of the array :

[image]

I could work around this by using an IFS function but that would require to write (and evaluate) the logical test for each pair of argument and that is what I would like to evade.

Maybe I am tackling this issue from the wrong angle but I would still like to know if this usage of SWITCH is somehow possible. Thank you in advance.

---

The answerS :

The one from Reddy Lutonadio is very flexible for list of distinct values. It is the one I accepted.

The one from Ron Rosenfeld is very compact, efficient, can work with real numbers but the lists must have the same length.

My opinion : Use IFS for more complex situations (and maybe add the LET function in the mix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a combination of `LET`, `SWITCH`, `FILTER`, `NOT` and `ISERROR` functions like shown on the formula below

```
=LET(x,SWITCH(MONTH(F1),{1,2,3},"T1",{4,5,6},"T2",{7,8,9},"T3",{10,11,12},"T4"),FILTER(x,NOT(ISERROR(x))))
```

- LET function: allows to calculate the `x` (which is the SWITCH formula) only once.
- NOT (ISERROR) functions: returns the rows that have no error.
- FILTER function: returns the only correct value.

[image]

Comment: @AlexandreRivara See edit. The formula is longer, but it returns the correct values now.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I tested it and it's quite clever. If I do not find a more "compact" answer within 24h I will gladly accept this one !

Answer (score 1):

Simpler may not be flexible enough for your needs.  But to return the same result, using `SWITCH`:

```
=SWITCH(INT((MONTH(A1)-1)/3)+1,1,"T1",2,"T2",3,"T3",4,"T4")
```

You can obtain the same result with a simpler formulas:

```
=TEXT(INT((MONTH(A1)-1)/3)+1,"\T0")    
=CHOOSE(INT((MONTH(A1)-1)/3)+1,"T1","T2","T3","T4")
```

Comment: Definitely solutions that appeal to mathematicians here. Using the `INT` function to map 1,2,3 to 1; 4,5,6 to 2, etc and making it work by using the "trick" of subtracting 1, converting and adding 1 back.

Comment: I very much appreciate those answers ! The idea of pulling the logical issue out of the values arguments and into the expression is very efficient. If I am sure to stick with numbers and that all the ranges have the same length then your answer is the best and if I want to be more flexible the answer of @ReddyLutonadio becomes a perfect fit. For now, I don't know which answer I will pick !